# Unable to load JVMCI shared library: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, graalvm

When i tried to do a task that involved the java virtual machine that i have installed(in my case **GraalVM 19 CE**) the error is throw:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load JVMCI shared
>   library: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

**Note**: I am using linux SO (fedora 30 workstation)

Answer (score 0):

Following command helped me to find out the package that generetes the error:

> $dnf whatprovides '*/libcrypt.so.1'

libxcrypt-compat-4.4.6-1.fc30.x86_64 : Compatibility library providing legacy API functions Repo        : updates Matched from: Filename    : /lib64/libcrypt.so.1

glibc-arm-linux-gnu-2.27-4.fc29.x86_64 : Cross Compiled GNU C Library targeted at arm-linux-gnu Repo        : fedora Matched from: Filename  : /usr/arm-linux-gnu/sys-root/lib/libcrypt.so.1

Then installe the package:

> $sudo dnf install libxcrypt-compat

For more detail you can see: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1340